# "'length' in Object(obj)" How does it work in js?

Tags: javascript

```
'length' in Object(obj)
```

How does the above statement works in JavaScript?

I have found the below JavaScript statement in angular.js lib

```
var length = 'length' in Object(obj) && obj.length;
```

Comment: [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Answer (score 2):

`Object(...)` converts primitives to object structure. Examples:

```
Object(null) // {}
Object(undefined) // {}
Object(10) // Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 10}
```

If you type `'length' in 10` it will throw an error, but `'length' in Object(10)` will not (returns false and blocks next statement, which would throw an error if `obj` has a primitive value).

Your code checks if `obj` variable is an array or array-like object (has length property).

More about [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Object) and [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

Answer (score 2):

That will check whether the property `length` exists in `Object(obj)` or not

I guess that is to differentiate between Array and Object.

Because Object doesn't have the property `length` so it will false for Object.

```js
var a = {
  name: "abc",
  age: "34"
};
var l = 'length' in Object(a) && a.length;
console.log(l);
```

But array have the property `length` and it will return the length of the array.

```js
var b = [34, 54, 65];
var ll = 'length' in Object(b) && b.length;
console.log(ll);
```

When we type checking them, both are same.

```js
var a = [];
var b = {};
console.log(typeof a, typeof b);
```

There are other methods to differentiate Array and Object too.

Using `Array.isArray`

```js
var a = [];
var b = {};

console.log(Array.isArray(a));

console.log(Array.isArray(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var length = Object.keys(myArray).length;
```

Or

> Universal function:-

```js
var objSize = function(obj) {
    var count = 0;
    
    if (typeof obj == "object") {
    
        if (Object.keys) {
            count = Object.keys(obj).length;
        } else if (window._) {
            count = _.keys(obj).length;
        } else if (window.$) {
            count = $.map(obj, function() { return 1; }).length;
        } else {
            for (var key in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) count++;
        }
        
    }
    
    return count;
};

document.write(objSize({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }));
```